# Where are /scripts/local-top and /scripts/local-premount?

Tags: linux, boot, systemd

[image: Screenshot of the bootup process for linux mint]

I looked at the bootup process of linux and have seen that it runs `/scripts/local-premount` and `/scripts/local-top`, but I couldn't any files or directories like that in the linux source code. I was wondering where the code for this is and is it run using `systemd` or by the kernel image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in `/scripts` inside your `/boot/initrd.img-<version>` image, which is generated from `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts` and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts`.