# run a date command before unlocking encrypted volume at startup

Tags: debian, luks, startup, cryptsetup

When the PC boots up I have to enter quite a long password to unlock the hard drive.

Next, Debian proceeds to boot, and only once it has booted and I have then entered the login credentials can I see the time.

Is it possible to run a `date` command before the drive is even unlocked or something else which will tell you the time so it can just dump it into the few lines which appear before you enter the password for `luks` / `cryptsetup`?

Comment: Theoretically, this could be done by customizing initramfs with a date executable, preferably statically compiled, and modified initramfs init script. Practically, it is more trouble than is worth: you would need to repeat the entire nonstandard customizing process whenever there is an update.

Comment: `date` is already provided by debian `busybox`; so it's a matter of running `date` command before `cryptsetup`. This should be possible to do in [a custom boot script](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs-tools.7.en.html#BOOT_SCRIPTS). Just throw it in `local-top` and see what happens. Alternatively patch /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot :: setup_mapping() directly, this could also be automated in a custom hook script so it survives updates.

Comment: Grub also has a `date` command so you can display it while loading kernel/initramfs, just put it into the `menuentry`. Some bios also display the time in their boot menu. All of these would happen before the clock is synced, so it depends on how reliable the hardware clock is. It might also not know about your timezone, for busybox date, you'd have to set the `TZ` variable accordingly.

Comment: @Vilinkameni that sounds like fun but indeed more trouble than it is worth. Especially as  initramfs is probably written in C and I am not that skilled with manipulating it, compiling it or writing it. @frostschutz I could be wrong but imagine that 'grub' comes to life only after 'cryptsetup'. What is `local-top` and where do you find it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452489/where-are-scripts-local-top-and-scripts-local-premount

Comment: Can't find a `/scripts/local-top` in Debian

Comment: Related: [Ramfs, rootfs and initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.html), [initramfs in Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/initramfs).

Comment: To add to @frostschutz's post: I don't know the specifics of Debian, but from his comment it seems it is similar to Arch, which I know when it comes to initramfs. Busybox already should provide a number of utilities in its statically compiled executable, so the first part is fulfilled. The second part comes to adding a custom initramfs hook, which the package manager automatically runs if needed. The specifics should be in the listed manual page and wiki.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I don't know what a "hook" is in this context. This sounds like a dangerous thing in that if I break the thing which offers the prompt to unlock cryptsetup / luks, I'll be truly locked out of the system. Probably won't destroy any data but it would lead to a time consuming recovery exercise with `gparted` etc. This is my "daily driver" PC not some prototype. If I work out how to do this I'd want to know that I won't somehow corrupt and kill intramfs or busybox or something else which is crucial.